# Prim's Algorithm implementation in C++ STL error?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, stl, prims-algorithm

I am trying to implement Prim's MST algorithm in C++ using STL.

But for the following program it seems to enter in an infinite loop. And then exits with an error.

Pseudo-code for Prim's MST Algorithm ;

[image]

My Code :

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<int>         vi;
typedef pair<int,int>       ii;
typedef vector<ii>          vii;

#define REP(i,a,b)  for(int i=int(a);i<b;i++)
#define TRvii(c,it) for(vii::iterator it=(c).begin();it!=(c).end();it++)

#define INF 2000000000

void Prims(int V, int s, vector<vii> &AdjList)
{
    vector<int> dist(V,INF);
    dist[s] = 0;
    priority_queue<ii,vector<ii>,greater<ii> > pq; 
    pq.push(ii(0,s));

    REP(i,1,V) pq.push(ii(i,INF));

    bool inPriorityQueue[V];
    REP(i,0,V) inPriorityQueue[i] = true;

    while(!pq.empty())
    {
        ii top = pq.top(); pq.pop();
        int d = top.first,u = top.second;

        inPriorityQueue[u] = false;

        TRvii(AdjList[u],it)
        {
            int v = it->first, weight_u_v = it->second;

            if(inPriorityQueue[v] && weight_u_v<dist[v])
            {
                dist[v] = weight_u_v;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "The shortest distance from " << s << " to all the nodes is" << endl;
    REP(i,0,V)
    {
        cout << i << " : " << dist[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{   
    int v,s,edges;

    printf("Enter number of vertices : ");
    scanf("%d",&v);

    vector<vii> adjList(v+1);

    printf("\nEnter source vertex : ");
    scanf("%d",&s);

    adjList[0].push_back(make_pair(1,4));
    adjList[0].push_back(make_pair(7,8));
    adjList[1].push_back(make_pair(0,4));
    adjList[1].push_back(make_pair(2,8));
    adjList[1].push_back(make_pair(7,11));
    adjList[7].push_back(make_pair(0,8));
    adjList[7].push_back(make_pair(1,11));
    adjList[7].push_back(make_pair(8,7));
    adjList[7].push_back(make_pair(6,1));
    adjList[2].push_back(make_pair(1,8));
    adjList[2].push_back(make_pair(3,7));
    adjList[2].push_back(make_pair(8,2));
    adjList[2].push_back(make_pair(5,4));
    adjList[8].push_back(make_pair(2,2));
    adjList[8].push_back(make_pair(7,7));
    adjList[8].push_back(make_pair(6,6));
    adjList[6].push_back(make_pair(7,1));
    adjList[6].push_back(make_pair(5,2));
    adjList[6].push_back(make_pair(8,2));
    adjList[5].push_back(make_pair(6,2));
    adjList[5].push_back(make_pair(2,4));
    adjList[5].push_back(make_pair(3,14));
    adjList[5].push_back(make_pair(4,10));
    adjList[4].push_back(make_pair(3,9));
    adjList[4].push_back(make_pair(5,10));
    adjList[3].push_back(make_pair(2,7));
    adjList[3].push_back(make_pair(5,14));
    adjList[3].push_back(make_pair(4,9));

    Prims(v, s, adjList);

    return 0;
}
```

Graph on which this algorithm is implemented :

[image]

Comment: A tip: If you want a large number to signify infinity, then I suggest [`std::numeric_limits<type>::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max).

Comment: As for your problem, start with a smaller set of input data (the graph) and step through the code line by line in a debugger to see what's happening.

Comment: It feels so bad even after 30 views, no one answers your question :(

Comment: Just FYI, these macros are an abomination. Don’t write code like this, it makes the code *less* readable. The typedefs are also obscure but at least they don’t come with all the disadvantages of macros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you had tried debugging it you would have very quickly found the problem lies with the line:

```
 TRvii(AdjList[u],it)
```

Think about what `u` is. In the first go around the `while` loop `u == s` due to `pq.push(ii(0,s));`. In the next, and all subsequent loops however, `u == INF` due to `REP(i,1,V) pq.push(ii(i,INF));`.

Trying to access `AdjList[INF]` is "bad" and results in undefined behaviour (a crash in your case).

I would suggest debugging your algorithm further, possibly with a simpler test case. Step through it and watch all variables. Assumably you understand the algorithm and what states it should go through so watch all the variables to make sure they are what they should be.